# How to passthrough alert angular json text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How do I passthrough a json entry into my onClick="alert(**x.AlertInfo**)" area of a JSON return array?

Trying to activate a message box which returns the string of a returned JSON entry onClick for an entire row. Specifically this entry. The rest of the table works fine, just this section.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in json.tags | filter:filterName | filter:filterID | orderBy:myOrderBy:reverse" onClick="alert(x.AlertInfo)">
```

Here is the full source code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="getJson">  
   <!-- <p>Status : {{statuscode}}</p>
    <p>StatusText : {{statustext}}</p>-->
    <input type="text" id="input" ng-model="filterName" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('t1')" width="8%">t1</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('t2')" width="5%">t2</th>
            <th ng-click="orderByMe('t3')" width="3%">t3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in json.tags | filter:filterName | filter:filterID | orderBy:myOrderBy:reverse" onClick="alert(x.AlertInfo)">
            <td>{{x.t1}}</td>
            <td>{{x.t2}}</td>
            <td>{{x.t3}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('getJson', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $scope.getData = function() {
            $http.get('http://JSONGET').
                then(function(response) {
                    $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                    $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                    $scope.json = response.data;
                    console.log('Feteched data!');
                });
         };

         $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
            $scope.myOrderBy = x;
         };

         $scope.intervalFunction = function(){
            $scope.getData();
            $interval(function(){
                $scope.getData();
            }, 15000);
         };

         $scope.intervalFunction()        

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't call alerts and consoles as an expression in html. What you can do is assign alert to scope function in controller

```
$scope.alert = window.alert;
```

now call the alert from the html. And use `ng-click` instead of `onClick`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in json.tags | filter:filterName | filter:filterID | orderBy:myOrderBy:reverse" ng-click="alert(x.AlertInfo)">
```

Comment: Needed to add $window into the controller, besides that everything went accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$winodw` service and `ng-click`, alert always work in ng-click, but if you want to manipulate some data.

```js
app.controller('getJson', function($scope, $http, $interval, $window) {
   // content and methods
   // ...
   // ...
   $scope.alertInfo = function(index) {
       var jsonData = $scope.json[index]; // json data of the clicked table-row
       $window.alert(jsonData.AlertInfo); // can manipulate, convert object to string or do whatever you want
   });
});
```

```html
<tr ... data-ng-click="alertInfo($index)">
   ...
</tr>
```